# Should there be a space before a percent sign?

Tags: numbers, typography, measuring-units, spacing

Should there be a space before a percent sign or not?
Should you write **20%** or **20 %**?

I'm not sure if there is any consensus about this or not. Is one way more common than the other?

Comment: If you add a space before the % sign, remember to use a non-breakable space

Comment: This is purely a matter of style. Different style guides/ schools of thought exist. It may not be desirable to set pseudo standards to encompass all situations and say "this is the right way to do it" here.

Comment: I have *never* seen a space between the number and the sign.

Comment: In Norwegian, it is the only correct way, the reasoning being that the symbol represents a word. Hence this applies to most such symbols, such as paragraph (§) or units of measurement. Degrees, minutes and seconds (degree, plus the primes) is a special case, as they are considered part of the number (denoting the number as sextagesimal), and therefore is written without spacing.

Comment: And how about “**wt%**?” “1 **wt%**?” “1**wt%**?”

Answer (score 59, accepted):

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent_sign#Spacing) there is no consensus on this in English:

> **There is no consensus as to whether or
>   not to include a space between the
>   number and percent sign in English**.
>   Many authorities prescribe that there
>   should be a space, whilst others
>   advise against it. The brochure of the
>   International System of Units declares
>   in chapter 5: "a space separates the
>   number and the symbol %". The ISO 31-0
>   standard also specifies a space, and
>   the TeX typesetting system encourages
>   using one. This is in accordance with
>   the general rule of adding a
>   non-breaking space between a numerical
>   value and its corresponding unit of
>   measurement. However, style guides –
>   such as the Chicago Manual of Style –
>   commonly prescribe to write the number
>   and percent sign without any space in
>   between.

Comment: That's what Wikipedia says, but I'm sceptical in this case. Another interpretation which I've heard, consistent with that passage, is that it's only the SI and ISO standards that insist on a space, while all "English" style guides advice against a space.

Comment: It would be interesting to know if there is more consensus in other languages. I am not a native English speaker myself. I'll try to investigate this case in Swedish.

Comment: Ok, I actually found a quick answer to this. In Swedish the current pracise is to follow the ISO-31 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_31) and "svenska skrivregler" (the regular writing rules for Swedish) agree.

Comment: I will add that German standards, too, use a space (see DIN 5008, Duden, etc.), but it appears that barely any German is aware of that. The style guidelines of the German Wikipedia agree that there should be a space, but even in their article *on the percent sign itself* that rule is occasionally ignored: for every instance with a space, there's another one without. So much for standards.

Comment: I'll have to accept this, even though Chicago style says otherwise. That ISO says one thing and, for example, Chicago style another I think hints at lack of consensus.

Comment: @Johan See also: my comment at the question above.

Comment: Yet another reason not to trust the Chicago Manual of Style.

Comment: A style guide is, after all, just a guide. ISO standards are internationally agreed upon _standards_, hence they should always trump any style guides’ suggestions. @Johan: For Norwegian, v. my comment to the question.

Comment: @Johan In Czech, it is with space for the noun (I am sure on 5 %) and without space for the adjective (5% growth).

Comment: For consistency with other symbols, it should have been  with space, but for aesthetic/readability it has been traditionally better without it, specially because the space  can be stretched a lot  or produce a line break. However, today  a mid-point is probably the best solution: a non-breakable small space like  U+202F

Answer (score 23):

There may be no consensus among the standards bodies, but outside of technical writing at least, it doesn't matter what the ISO says. Modern U.S. usage *overwhelmingly* uses no space. Note that Wikipedia uses no space, as in the article for [Percentage](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Percentage&oldid=493105656).

### Demonstration

As a demonstration, one can download [the first billion bytes of an English Wikipedia database dump](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/enwik9.zip) (commonly used as a test file for data compression benchmarks):

```
user@host:/run/shm$ wget http://mattmahoney.net/dc/enwik9.zip
```

and count the (approximate) number of occurrences of `50 %` and `50%`:

```
user@host:/run/shm$ unzip -p enwik9.zip | fold | grep '50 %' | wc --lines
71
```

vs.

```
user@host:/run/shm$ unzip -p enwik9.zip | fold | grep '50%' | wc --lines
9216
```

(The first 1 usages of `50 %` are:

```
On efficacy measures, a successful antidepressant trial involves just 50 % or mo
 signifies a mere 50 % or greater reduction in depression symptoms as opposed to
* '''Beta brasses''', with 45-50 % zinc content, can only be worked hot, is hard
* '''White brass''' contains more than 50 % zinc and is too brittle for general 
was very profitable for the V.O.C., initially yielding profits of 50 % or even m
s 40 to 50 % of the capacity of the elevator. The grooves in the drive sheave ar
nt process, usually requiring at least 50 % more electricity than the energy sto
 50 % and this in turn affected both the trade-in value of used vehicles and the
er molecules. Water containing 50 % H and 50 % D actually contains about 50 % HD
he 1980s. About 50 % of these moves were within the same prefecture; the others
```

and of `50%`:

```
 50% higher than nearby forested areas because snow does not cover the trees as 
<table border=0 cellpadding=2 cellspacing=2 width=50%>
 Afghanistan as being [[Persian language|Persian]] (local name: [[Dari]]) 50% an
Note: Albania has a large gray economy that may be as large as 50% of official G
rriages occur very early in a pregnancy. Approximately 10-50% of pregnancies end
tal, and a 20% increase since 1981, 50% since 1971. Major towns are Peterhead (1
MND is typically fatal within 2-5 years. Around 50% die within 14 months of diag
nosis. The remaining 50% will not necessarily die within the next 14 months as t
n up to 50% of SOD1 cases. In people of [[Scandinavia]]n extraction there is a r
[[Cognitive]] change can and does occur in between 33&ndash;50% of patients.
```

)

Comment: Without space more common in English then. In Swedish, with space seems more common.

Comment: That demonstration is pretty much useless without more sophisticated filtering. Why focus on '50 %' only? And obviously your current method catches HTML snippets such as `width=50%` -- I guess there are plenty of them in the database.

Comment: Instead of `grep`ping for normal space only, consider that one could use a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) and other variants thereof, plus other numbers, plus @Jan-PhilipGehrcke has a valid point about snippets. So you could use e.g. `grep -Poe '(?<=[^=\d])\d+%'` and [`grep -Poe '(?<=[^=\d])\d+(?:\p{Zs}|&\w+;)%'`](https://regex101.com/r/TxhYBj/1). The `-P` is necessary for the character classes (e.g. `\d` for any digit) to work, the [`-o`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6985/863) outputs multiple matches per input line to one line per match so `wc -l` actually counts all matches.

Comment: ... calling `fold` seems unnecessary to me (or even falsify the results). With my RegEx I get 2644:936770. _However_, the majority of Wikipedia editors doing this merely proves your point that the space is mostly neglected, but not whether it _should_ be there or not. From what I read, German people tend to omit the there-mandatory space for example, yet that doesn't magically modify the respective norm. But it does look weird, I prefer a [thin space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) " "...

Answer (score 22):

When the symbol % is used, there should be no space. When the "percent" word is used, there should be space.

Examples from the [Chicago Manual of Style Online](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch09/ch09_sec018.html?para=):

> Fewer than 3 percent of the employees
> used public transportation.
>
> With 90–95
> percent of the work complete, we can
> relax.
>
> A 75 percent likelihood of
> winning is worth the effort.
>
> Her
> five-year certificate of deposit
> carries an interest rate of 5.9
> percent.
>
> Only 20% of the ants were
> observed to react to the stimulus.
>
> The
> treatment resulted in a 20%–25%
> increase in reports of night
> blindness.

The manual explicitly advices the following:

> Note also that no space appears
> between the numeral and the symbol %.